# What is xcscheme file? What is it purpose?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a newbie learning the iOS.

Can someone please explain what is the purpose of the xcscheme file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What's inside the xcscheme file?  These are the actions and configurations that happen when you build, run, test, profile, etc.  These can be changed from Xcode user to user, which makes it friendly for using on multi-developer projects.

These are the same items you see within Xcode when you click on the "Edit Scheme" popup menu choice:

[image: Edit Scheme]

Comment: If you mark a scheme as "Shared" then it is stored in xcshareddata/xschemes and probably should be put under version control.